# GroupSequence with validators from inherited classes dont seem to work correctly

Tags: php, constraints, fosuserbundle, symfony4

Currently I am a little bit stuck:

I want to create a special validation to my user object that only is executed when all other validations succeed.
This can be solved with the @GroupSequence and validators in groups prior to the final group containing my "special" validator:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

    ...

/*
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"User", "Strict"})
 * @UniqueEntity("email", message="xx", groups={"User"})
 * @MyAssert\UserValidConstraint(groups={"Strict"})
*/

class User extends BaseUser {

    ....

}
```

With this, my UserValidConstraint is not executed when the email is not unique - that is expected and this is the behavior I want to get.

Also the constraints from the base-class are executed. I get the error messages from the base class if the password is too short etc. Also working as expected.
But my Problem is that my special constraint is also always executed when these validations of the base class fail.
It seems that those validations somehow are not recognized by this GroupSequence-Rule.

Any hints what I might be doing wrong? Or is that a bug in Symfony?

Using
Symfony 4.1.4
FOS Userbundle from git/dev-master

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is a little bit strange:
In order to evaluate the problem, I wrote some unit-tests to learn about the behavior of the validators.
There I could verify that GroupSequence correctly works with inherited classes.

The constraint in question is one from FOS-Userbundle. There the constraints are defined with YAML whereas my constraints are defined by annotations. Maybe there is the problem?

As a workaround I added another UniqueConstraint for the email address in my user class and gave that an empty error-message. So the user is not too confused about the extra error. ;-)